# Dockerfile automatically run passenger start with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, passenger, dockerfile

I've built a `Rails` image with docker, but now I don't know how to use Dockerfile to set the `passenger`.

My `Dockerfile` now is

```
FROM username/my_app:latest
WORKDIR /my_app
# Expose port 3000 to the Docker host, so we can access it from the outside.
EXPOSE 3000
```

Now I have to run the container first, and then execute the `passenger` command like this.

```
docker run -it -p 4321:3000 \
--name my_app \
username/my_app
```

Then typing

```
docker exec -itd my_app /bin/bash -c -l "whenever -iw"
docker exec -it my_app /bin/bash -c -l "passenger start"
```

Finally, I can access my app in http://localhost:4321

Is there a way I can only using `docker run ....` to automatically start my app and turn the `passenger start` ?

I've tried this, but it seems not work.

```
FROM username/my_app:latest
WORKDIR /my_app
RUN whenever -iw
RUN passenger start
# Expose port 3000 to the Docker host, so we can access it from the outside.
EXPOSE 3000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ENTRYPOINT` to execute command after starting container.

```
FROM username/my_app:latest
WORKDIR /my_app
# Expose port 3000 to the Docker host, so we can access it from the outside.
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT ["whenever -iw && passenger start "]
```

For more info about `ENTRYPOINT` refer below links:

[Dockerfile Entrypoint documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint)

Comment: It throw docker: `Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"whenever -iw && passenger start \": executable file not found in $PATH".`

Comment: either `whenever` package is not installed or it is not able to find command path. first manually launch container as you are doing and check both command is correct and able to run if you run like `whenever -iw && passenger start`  or may be it use /bin/sh shell bydefault that is not detecting these binary path. if both command not executing together and separately working then make shell script file and add these two command to script and add this script to docker file . give script path in entrypoint file.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.